# Radio buttons not working

Tags: html, css, radio-button

My radio buttons are not working. They are not clickable...

Below you find the javascript coding, and below that the CSS styling.

```css
input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
  }

input[type=radio] + label, input[type=checkbox] + label {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:-2px;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#fff),to(#e6e6e6));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff',endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6',GradientType=0);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  }

   input[type=radio]:checked + label, input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
       background-image: none;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
      background-color:#e0e0e0;
  }
```

```html
<div id="option">
    
    <input type="radio" id="all" name="datesize" value="731" checked="checked"><label for="all">all</label>
    <input type="radio" id="year" name="datesize" value="365"><label for="all">year</label>
    <input type="radio" id="season" name="datesize" value="91"><label for="all">quarter</label>
    <input type="radio" id="month" name="datesize" value="30"><label for="all">month</label>
    <div id="chooseall"></div>
    <div id="chooseyear" style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="radio" id="yearpick0" name="yearpick" value="0" checked="checked"> 2011 
        <input type="radio" id="yearpick1" name="yearpick" value="1"> 2012
    </div>
    <div id="chooseseason" style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="radio" id="quarterpick0" name="quarterpick" value="0" checked="checked"> jan-mar 
        <input type="radio" id="quarterpick1" name="quarterpick" value="1"> apr-jun
        <input type="radio" id="quarterpick2" name="quarterpick" value="2"> jul-sep 
        <input type="radio" id="quarterpick3" name="quarterpick" value="3"> oct-dec
    </div>
    <div id="choosemonth" style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick0" name="monthpick" value="0" checked="checked"> jan 
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick1" name="monthpick" value="1"> feb
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick2" name="monthpick" value="2"> mar 
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick3" name="monthpick" value="3"> apr
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick4" name="monthpick" value="0"> may 
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick5" name="monthpick" value="1"> jun
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick6" name="monthpick" value="2"> jul 
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick7" name="monthpick" value="3"> aug
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick8" name="monthpick" value="0"> sep 
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick9" name="monthpick" value="1"> oct
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick10" name="monthpick" value="10"> nov 
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick11" name="monthpick" value="11"> dec
    </div>

</div>
```

Please have a look at the code and see if you know what the problem is. Thnx!

Comment: There is no JS in your code.

Comment: Your labels are all pointing to the same id "all", you need to change them to the id of the relevant radio button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your label's are all mapped to the wrong id, change that to:

```
<input type="radio" id="all" name="datesize" value="731" checked="checked"><label for="all">all</label>
<input type="radio" id="year" name="datesize" value="365"><label for="year">year</label>
<input type="radio" id="season" name="datesize" value="91"><label for="season">quarter</label>
<input type="radio" id="month" name="datesize" value="30"><label for="month">month</label>
```

Also if your inputs are display: none, please check if it works cross browser, seem to work for me in chrome.

Also the input data wont be send as part of a form if you hide it using display none, better to visually hide it if you need this.

Here is the working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/kg7b8gb5/1/

Comment: My bad, forgot to save the changes I made to the label for elements, now its done and link updated. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` attribute in the `label` should refer to the `id` attribute of the `input` like below:

```
....
     <input type="radio" id="year" name="datesize" value="365"><label for="year">year</label>
....
```

See it working below after the change.

```css
input[type=radio],
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=radio] + label,
input[type=checkbox] + label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -2px;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#fff), to(#e6e6e6));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #e6e6e6);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label,
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  background-image: none;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<div id="option">

  <input type="radio" id="all" name="datesize" value="731" checked="checked">
  <label for="all">all</label>
  <input type="radio" id="year" name="datesize" value="365">
  <label for="year">year</label>
  <input type="radio" id="season" name="datesize" value="91">
  <label for="season">quarter</label>
  <input type="radio" id="month" name="datesize" value="30">
  <label for="month">month</label>
  <div id="chooseall"></div>
  <div id="chooseyear" style="visibility:hidden">
    <input type="radio" id="yearpick0" name="yearpick" value="0" checked="checked">2011
    <input type="radio" id="yearpick1" name="yearpick" value="1">2012
  </div>
  <div id="chooseseason" style="visibility:hidden">
    <input type="radio" id="quarterpick0" name="quarterpick" value="0" checked="checked">jan-mar
    <input type="radio" id="quarterpick1" name="quarterpick" value="1">apr-jun
    <input type="radio" id="quarterpick2" name="quarterpick" value="2">jul-sep
    <input type="radio" id="quarterpick3" name="quarterpick" value="3">oct-dec
  </div>
  <div id="choosemonth" style="visibility:hidden">
    <input type="radio" id="monthpick0" name="monthpick" value="0" checked="checked">jan
    <input type="radio" id="monthpick1" name="monthpick" value="1">feb
    <input type="radio" id="monthpick2" name="monthpick" value="2">mar
    <input type="radio" id="monthpick3" name="monthpick" value="3">apr
    <input type="radio" id="monthpick4" name="monthpick" value="0">may
    <input type="radio" id="monthpick5" name="monthpick" value="1">jun
    <input type="radio" id="monthpick6" name="monthpick" value="2">jul
    <input type="radio" id="monthpick7" name="monthpick" value="3">aug
    <input type="radio" id="monthpick8" name="monthpick" value="0">sep
    <input type="radio" id="monthpick9" name="monthpick" value="1">oct
    <input type="radio" id="monthpick10" name="monthpick" value="10">nov
    <input type="radio" id="monthpick11" name="monthpick" value="11">dec
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In css you have

```
input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
  }
```

which makes radio and checkboxes hidden which make them not clickable. 
Looks like you are customizing radio or checkboxes and You pasted only a part of code or You are not aware of `display:none` is there in code

Comment: I want the radio to be hidden, and only see the text. I am able to click when I remove display:none, but I want to be able to click on the text... Do you Know how I do this?

Answer (score 0):

**CSS Layout - The display Property**
`display: none; is commonly used with JavaScript to hide and show elements without deleting and recreating them. Take a look at our last example on this page if you want to know how this can be achieved.`

remove this css `input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
  }`

learn more about it -http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp
The  element use display: none; as its default.

https://fiddle.jshell.net/

```css
input[type=radio] + label, input[type=checkbox] + label {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:-2px;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#fff),to(#e6e6e6));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff',endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6',GradientType=0);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  }

   input[type=radio]:checked + label, input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
       background-image: none;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
      background-color:#e0e0e0;
  }
```

```html
<div id="option">
    
    <input type="radio" id="all" name="datesize" value="731" checked="checked"><label for="all">all</label>
    <input type="radio" id="year" name="datesize" value="365"><label for="all">year</label>
    <input type="radio" id="season" name="datesize" value="91"><label for="all">quarter</label>
    <input type="radio" id="month" name="datesize" value="30"><label for="all">month</label>
    <div id="chooseall"></div>
    <div id="chooseyear" style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="radio"id="yearpick0" name="yearpick" value="0" checked="checked"> 2011 
        <input type="radio" id="yearpick1" name="yearpick" value="1"> 2012
    </div>
    <div id="chooseseason" style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="radio" id="quarterpick0" name="quarterpick" value="0" checked="checked"> jan-mar 
        <input type="radio" id="quarterpick1" name="quarterpick" value="1"> apr-jun
        <input type="radio" id="quarterpick2" name="quarterpick" value="2"> jul-sep 
        <input type="radio" id="quarterpick3" name="quarterpick" value="3"> oct-dec
    </div>
    <div id="choosemonth" style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick0" name="monthpick" value="0" checked="checked"> jan 
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick1" name="monthpick" value="1"> feb
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick2" name="monthpick" value="2"> mar 
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick3" name="monthpick" value="3"> apr
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick4" name="monthpick" value="0"> may 
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick5" name="monthpick" value="1"> jun
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick6" name="monthpick" value="2"> jul 
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick7" name="monthpick" value="3"> aug
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick8" name="monthpick" value="0"> sep 
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick9" name="monthpick" value="1"> oct
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick10" name="monthpick" value="10"> nov 
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick11" name="monthpick" value="11"> dec
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

put this:

```
<input type="radio" id="all" name="datesize" value="731" checked="checked"><label for="all">all</label>
<input type="radio" id="year" name="datesize" value="365"><label for="year">year</label>
<input type="radio" id="season" name="datesize" value="91"><label for="season">season</label>
<input type="radio" id="month" name="datesize" value="30"><label for="month">month</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `display:none`. added following css

```
input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
```

```css
input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;
    opacity: 0;
  }

input[type=radio] + label, input[type=checkbox] + label {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:-2px;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#fff),to(#e6e6e6));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff',endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6',GradientType=0);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  }

   input[type=radio]:checked + label, input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
       background-image: none;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
      background-color:#e0e0e0;
  }
```

```html
<div id="option">
    
    <input type="radio" id="all" name="datesize" value="731" checked="checked"><label for="all">all</label>
    <input type="radio" id="year" name="datesize" value="365"><label for="all">year</label>
    <input type="radio" id="season" name="datesize" value="91"><label for="all">quarter</label>
    <input type="radio" id="month" name="datesize" value="30"><label for="all">month</label>
    <div id="chooseall"></div>
    <div id="chooseyear" style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="radio" id="yearpick0" name="yearpick" value="0" checked="checked"> 2011 
        <input type="radio" id="yearpick1" name="yearpick" value="1"> 2012
    </div>
    <div id="chooseseason" style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="radio" id="quarterpick0" name="quarterpick" value="0" checked="checked"> jan-mar 
        <input type="radio" id="quarterpick1" name="quarterpick" value="1"> apr-jun
        <input type="radio" id="quarterpick2" name="quarterpick" value="2"> jul-sep 
        <input type="radio" id="quarterpick3" name="quarterpick" value="3"> oct-dec
    </div>
    <div id="choosemonth" style="visibility:hidden">
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick0" name="monthpick" value="0" checked="checked"> jan 
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick1" name="monthpick" value="1"> feb
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick2" name="monthpick" value="2"> mar 
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick3" name="monthpick" value="3"> apr
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick4" name="monthpick" value="0"> may 
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick5" name="monthpick" value="1"> jun
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick6" name="monthpick" value="2"> jul 
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick7" name="monthpick" value="3"> aug
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick8" name="monthpick" value="0"> sep 
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick9" name="monthpick" value="1"> oct
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick10" name="monthpick" value="10"> nov 
        <input type="radio" id="monthpick11" name="monthpick" value="11"> dec
    </div>

</div>
```